# failed: Cannot find module '../bin/napi-v3/win32/ia32/onnxruntime_binding.node in HuggingFaceTransformersEmbeddings

Tags: typescript, huggingface-transformers, langchain, huggingface, onnxruntime

I am building a VS Code extension in TypeScript. For one feature, I am using the HuggingFaceTransformersEmbeddings module for embedding files. When I run it in debug mode, it's working fine. However, when I build the VSIX and install it, I am getting an activation error.

```
import { HuggingFaceTransformersEmbeddings } from "@langchain/community/embeddings/hf_transformers";

Activating extension 'xyz-vscode-extension' failed: Cannot find module '../bin/napi-v3/win32/x64/onnxruntime_binding.node'
```